# django-rest-framework add SerializerMethodField to Serializer dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a lot of similar fields that should be created in a similar way.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_friend = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_is_friend')
    # ...

    def get_is_friend(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        return user.id in obj.friend_list
    # ...

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'is_friend',
            # ...
        )
```

Currently I have a decorator, it makes all I need, except creating `SerializerMethodField`.

```
def additional_fields_decorator(cls):
    relation_methods = (
        {
            'name': 'is_friend',
            'field_name': 'friends',
        },
        # ...
    )

    def relation_method_factory(field_name):
        def wrapper(self, obj):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            return user.id in getattr(obj, field_name)
        return wrapper

    for method in relation_methods:
        name = method['name']
        name_getter = 'get_{0}'.format(name)

        setattr(cls, name_getter, relation_method_factory(method['field_name']))
        cls.Meta.fields += (name,)
        # following line fails
        setattr(cls, name, serializers.SerializerMethodField(name_getter))

    return cls


@additional_fields_decorator
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pass
```

Who knows why `SerializerMethodField` cannot be created outside of the Serializer class?

Answer (score 2):

When DRF processes your `UserSerializer` class it looks for `SerializerMethodField` in the scope of the class. Hence when you declare the method outside of class it won't see it.

Comment: So you want to say that I need to patch scope of wrapped class?

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered a similar problem and I think you can dynamically add `SerializerMethodField` by dynamically create a serializer class using the type built-in method. Something like this:

```py
def generate_serializer(new_field):
    all_fields = ['field1', 'field2', new_field]

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = all_fields

    def generate_new_field_method(key):
        def get_new_field(self, instance):
            # some logic based on field name
            pass
        return get_new_field

    dct = {
        'new_field': serializers.SerializerMethodField(),
        'get_new_field': generate_new_field_method(new_field),
        'Meta': Meta,
    }

    return type('DynamicSerializer', (serializers.ModelSerializer,), dct)
```

The above example dynamically add a single field, but you can easily modify it to add a list of fields.